# Docker container fails on production server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nestjs

I have docker container with nestjs application. Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

it's section in docker-compose

```
backend:
container_name: backend
networks:
  - web
  - internal
environment:
  - DB_PASS=pass
  - DB_HOST=database
  - DB_USER=postgres
  - DB_NAME=postgres
  - DB_PORT=5432
  - NODE_ENV=production
  - VERSION=1.0
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
depends_on:
  - database
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.port=3001"
  - "traefik.docker.network=web"
  - "traefik.http.routers.backendo.entrypoints=http,https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.backendo.rule=Host(`mydomain.example`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.backendo.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.backendo.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
```

When I am trying to run this container on the production server it fails with error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', 
requireStack: []
```

But on my local machine, it works just fine.
I am wondering why there is a different result with the same docker-compose file. Isn't the main purpose of docker to let me don't worry about dependencies?

Comment: How are you deploying in production?  Are deploying on swarm or just running docker-compose on the server?

Comment: @Carlos just running `docker-compose up -d`, the same command I am using for testing on my local machine before deploying

Comment: I assume you are cloning your repo on the prod server and then running that command from within that folder?

Comment: @Carlos yep, you're right

Comment: Just for testing, have you tried removing the volume declaration when running in prod?

Comment: Actually I would even try that on your local as well.

Comment: @Carlos trying it rn. I gues it can help, cause I didn't run `npm i` on production server, so maybe my project folder without dependencies installed just replaced same folder within container

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221377/discussion-between---and-carlos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `volumes:` overwrite everything the Dockerfile does with content from your local system.  When you go to deploy it, the production system has different content in its host filesystem, so the image content gets overwritten with something different, and you get inconsistent results.

You should delete the `volumes:` from your `docker-compose.yml` file.  You should do this on your development system, too, so that you're using the actual image you're deploying when you do your local integration testing.  You can use a local Node installation for day-to-day development.